# How to connect to oracle database using apache-camel?

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, apache-karaf

Currently I am reading endpoints from a property file. I want to fetch them from DB. I have written a separate java file to connect to DB but karaf throws an exception.

I added packages in pom.xml too

Export-Package: oracle.jdbc, oracle.jdbc.driver

Import-Package: !javax.*, !oracle.**

```
    // Reading endpoints from property file
    String endPoint1 = propInfo.hashprops.get("endpoint1");
    String endPoint2 = propInfo.hashprops.get("endpoint2");
    from(endPoint1)
    .doTry()
    .setHeader(userid, constant("abcd"))
    .setHeader(password, constant("abcd"))
    .to(endPoint2)
    .doCatch(ConnectException.class)
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
            ex.getIn().setBody("Exception "));
        }
    })
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
            ex.getIn().setBody("Exception "));
        }
    });
```

If I try to read it from DB

```
   DbConnect obj = new DbConnect();
    String endPoint1 = obj.getEndpoint("endpoint1");
    String endPoint2 = obj.getEndpoint("endpoint2");
    from(endPoint1)
    .doTry()
    .setHeader(userid, constant("abcd"))
    .setHeader(password, constant("abcd"))
    .to(endPoint2)
    .doCatch(ConnectException.class)
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
            ex.getIn().setBody("Exception "));
        }
    })
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
            ex.getIn().setBody("Exception "));
        }
    });
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not
>   found by com.app.routes [246]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap oracle database drivers into osgi bundle:
`install -s wrap:file:///LOCAL_PATH/ojdbc6.jar` or `install -s wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.2.0`.

Check via console that wrapped drivers bundle was loaded and started.

Add oracle dependency to your bundle with database connection:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And now import desired packages:

`Import-Package : oracle.jdbc, oracle.jdbc.driver, oracle.jdbc.pool`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Alexey thanks for the quick reply, it was helpful. I added the dependency and wrapped oracle database drivers. 
Now am getting different errors like 
Unable to resolve 246.15: missing requirement [246.15] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=oracle.ons) missing requirement [246.15] osgi.wiring.package;(osgi.wiring.package=oracle.security.pki)

Do I need to add any extra jars? or how do I avoid those packages not extracting into META-INF.mf file ?

Comment: Hi @Siddesh B S, i'm using import only one package: `oracle.jdbc.pool`, because i'm using class `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` as datasource. You can download desired data from database by other Camel route (**jdbc**, **sql**, **jpa** components). Camel will need only datasource. But that route must download data before your main route started. I think you got this errors because your connection code use that packages. They are contained in such jars: ons.jar, oraclepki.jar.

Comment: Wow, I removed unnecessary import statements from pom.xml, It worked for me I added only `oracle.jdbc` that's enough to establish the connection. thank you. @Alexey